# JScrollPane content resizing issue

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, flowlayout

I have a JScrollPane containing a JList, as shown in the following image..

[image]

But when I resize the window, the JList inside does not resize, as shown below.

[image]

I want that the JBList width is set to the width of the Srollpane it is in. The JBList element has a flow layout and I expected it to resize automatically.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Looks more like a candidate for a `JTable`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the JScrollPane in the CENTER of a [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html)